# Killing Libgdx process without kiling the entire application

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, desktop-application

I am working on a 2D-3D Game on Java, with the help of Libgdx for the 3D Part. By now, I have menus and the 2D game written purely on Java, and I want to do the 3D part with Libgdx.

So I have managed to start a libgdx application (for desktop) and paint a plane and a box, and the box can be moved around, like the camera.

The problem is that only *that* part is written with the help of Libgdx. The menus and other stuff are written with Java and I don't want to change that.

So I clic a Button on the Java menu and the 3D game starts like this:

```
public static LwjglApplication main() {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.forceExit = false;
    config.height = Game.HEIGHT;
    config.width = Game.WIDTH;
    config.title = "Game 3D";
    return new LwjglApplication(new SuperBomberman3D(), config);
}
```

So now I get the new window, and that works. With F1, I close the game like this:

```
game3D.exit();
```

being Game3D the application returned by main().

And the next step is clicking the 3D Game button again, and the window opens again. Though, this time, **the window is not the size I have said in config**. That's weird.

Anyway, I try to open and close the 3D window a couple of times, and at some point, and exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport(GL11.java:3261)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGL20.glViewport(LwjglGL20.java:839)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setWindowedMode(LwjglGraphics.java:491)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:166)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

I have looked over the Internet, but nothing seems to fit in my problem. I don't call any method, besides the exit() method, outside the SuperBomberman3D class. I don't know where this error is being thrown or why. Anyway, here is the SuperBomberman3D class, in case you see something wrong there:

```
public class SuperBomberman3D extends ApplicationAdapter implements
    ApplicationListener {

public static LwjglApplication main() {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.forceExit = false;
    config.height = Game.HEIGHT;
    config.width = Game.WIDTH;
    config.title = "Super Bomberman 3D";
    return new LwjglApplication(new SuperBomberman3D(), config);
}

public PerspectiveCamera cam;
public CameraInputController camController;

public Model bombermanModel;
public Model planeModel;
public Environment env;
public ModelBatch modelBatch;

public ModelInstance bomberman;
public ModelInstance plane;

private int FIELD_OF_VIEW = 67;

private Vector3 initialPosition = new Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f);
private Vector3 origin = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
private float near = 1f;
private float far = 300f;

@Override
public void create() {
    camera();
    models();
    environment();
}

private void camera() {
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(FIELD_OF_VIEW, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(initialPosition);
    cam.lookAt(origin);
    cam.near = near;
    cam.far = far;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
}

private void models() {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    ModelBuilder mb = new ModelBuilder();
    bombermanModel = mb.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f,
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED)),
            Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
    bomberman = new ModelInstance(bombermanModel);

    planeModel = mb.createRect(-10, 0, 10,
            10, 0, 10,
            10, 0, -10,
            -10, 0, -10,
            0, 1, 0,
            GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
            new Material(
                new ColorAttribute(
                    ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.BLUE)),
                new BlendingAttribute(
                    GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA,
                    GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)),
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position |
            VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);
    plane = new ModelInstance(planeModel);
}

private void environment() {
    env = new Environment();
    env.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.2f, 0.2f,
            0.2f, 1f));
    env.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));
}

@Override
public void render() {
    step();

    camController.update();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(bomberman, env);
    modelBatch.render(plane, env);
    modelBatch.end();
}

public void step() {
    float x = 0;
    float z = 0;

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
        x = -0.2f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)){
        x = 0.2f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
        z = 0.2f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
        z = -0.2f;
    }

    bomberman.transform.translate(new Vector3(x, 0, z));

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.F1)){
        StatesMachine.goToRoom(STATE.MAIN_MENU, false);
    }
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    bombermanModel.dispose();
    planeModel.dispose();
    modelBatch.dispose();
}
```

}

So, the question is why is that error being thrown, how do i put things right, and, on other note, why the configuration is only set well once, when I call `game3D.exit()` to exit the 3D application and I redo the application with the main() method.

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded? if so read this....[LibGDX Multithreading](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading)  it explains about the rendering thread and interactions with any other thread.

Comment: But the thing is I only start and close the game in other thread, and no more operations considering 3D are outside the SuperBomberman3D class.

Anyway, I tried putting the game3D.exit() part in a post-runnable, but it didn't work ):

Comment: Some other things that could be happening.... That you are calling on OpenGL stuff before its ready, as in constructing items that require  LibGDX has finished establishing that. I know when i first started using LibGDX i had similar issues that I could no reproduce in a specific way. This might be something similar where it comes to being a race condition, where usually OpenGL Context set up wins, but in the case of application open and close, the OpenGL context might be loosing to your apps method calls.

Comment: I don't know, the first two calls are okay. The second call just messes up with the window, dunno why, and the third **always** fails with the same exception. I mean, it's weird that the configuration setup only works once, and the third time always fails.

Comment: Instead of ending the application, why do you not create a sub application that has all of the game related cams, keys, code, ect and instead of calling .exit(); you write in some swapping method. You could make it easy by having a "running-game" deal and then swap apps in and out of the running game design.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying. I have my 2D game written purely in Java, and it doesn't have cams, for example. How can I swap two apps, anyway?